# First and last index of a sequence

Tags: python, sequence

I'm interested in finding the first and the last index on a sequence of at least three identical numbers( they have to be in a row ). If there are more sequences, the indexes (start-end) will pe appended to a list. Example:
`s = [1,1,1,1,4,1,1,1]  --> output: [0,3,5,7]`

```
s = [1,1,1,1,4,1,1,1]
c = []
indexes = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s.count(s[i]) >= 3:
        c.append(i)
```

`my output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, try using this code to solve your problem:

```py
prev_value = s[0]
prev_index = 0
consecutive_count = 0

for index, value in enumerate(s):
    if value == prev_value:
        consecutive_count += 1
    else:
        if consecutive_count > 2:
             indexes.append(prev_index)
             indexes.append(index - 1)
        consecutive_count = 1
        prev_value = value
        prev_index = index

if consecutive_count > 2:
    indexes.append(prev_index)
    indexes.append(index)
```

Comment: Great! If the code worked, I would appreciate it if you could accept the answer :)

Comment: Running this I get a result of `[0, 3]`.

Comment: I changed `consecutive_count = 0` to `= 1` in the last edit. That should fix it.

Comment: Yes, it did. :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Let's start with the following:

```
s = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1]
for value, group in itertools.groupby(s):
    # print(value)
    print(list(group))
```

This will give you

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[4]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Now let's add your condition and keep track of the current position.

```
s = [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1]
positions = []
current_position = 0
for value, group in itertools.groupby(s):
    group_length = len(list(group))
    if group_length >= 3:
        positions.extend([current_position, current_position + group_length - 1])
    current_position += group_length
print(positions)
```

This will give you the desired result `[0, 3, 5, 7]`.

Comment: Even if you might not use this solution please remember the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module. It has several functions that might come in quite handy.

Comment: I'll dig in tomorrow and I'll break in pieces both answers, thank you!